# indexOf ckecking if there is not words

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains, indexof

I have problem with indexOf.

I have search and when I type something, **.mark-select li** will disappear or appear, depend on key word, I want to do something when there is not words in search that contains in **.marka-select li** . I don't know how to check when there is not same words.
Help please!

This is my code :

```
$("#marka").keyup(function() {
    var marka = $("#marka").val().toLowerCase();

    if(marka != "") {
        $(".marka-select li").hide();

        $(".marka-select li").each(function() {
            var trenutna_marka = $(this).attr("data-keywords").toLowerCase();

            if(trenutna_marka.indexOf(marka) >=0) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".marka-select li").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: What does not work with the script you tried? Can you post some example markup with some example `data-keywords`, and tell us which input you enter in `#marka` that yields unexpected results?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the answer, i will try to explane,
Example: .marka-select li keywords are job and bold
When i start typing : j (show me job), jo (show me job), jos (show me nothing, and then i want to do something, to put some alert, or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible that I just do not understand the question but why not just add an else statement to your if indexOf check?

```
if(trenutna_marka.indexOf(marka) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
           ... do something else ...
        }
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer

Yes, i think like that but there is problem, because of each.

Each pass through all keywords every time.

Example keywords JOB and BOLD.

When I start typing J( each check job and bold). And each pass through if and else in same time.

That mean every time I type something, if loop will be passed, and else too.

Do you understand me?